# Pandas Data frame Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quandl

I am trying to make some analysis on data received from Quandl.

Following code was implemented by me:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

df=quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")
df=df[['Adj. High','Adj. Low',]]

df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High']) - df(['Adj. Low']) / df['Adj. Low']*100.0

df=df[['HL_PCT',]]
print(df.head())
```

I am getting the error as:

> df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High']) - df(['Adj. Low']) / df['Adj. Low']*100.0
>   TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

I think there is typo with `()` in `df(['Adj. Low'])` - use `df['Adj. Low']`:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
df=quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")

df=df[['Adj. High','Adj. Low']]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Low']) / df['Adj. Low']*100.0
df=df[['HL_PCT']]

print(df.head())
```

Comment: Yes...Sorry couldn't interpret the error...thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']]
var1 = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0
df['HL_PCT'] = var1.var()
var2 = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0
df['PCT_change'] = var2.var()
df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]
print(df.head())
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your code. it will be easier to understand other users.